# How can I place MoM values over a line and clustered column chart in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

Want to place Month Over Month values above the chart. This MoM calculation is based on a monthly product units sales.

[image]

I`d like to know how to position MoM values above the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With native visuals, this is not possible. However, this can be done with [Deneb](https://deneb-viz.github.io/) custom visual which is free and certified.